# unzip multi protected zip files using fcrackzip

Tags: bash, passwords, unzip

I have around 50000 zip files protected with password and all those password are stored in one dictionary file but not arranged , 
if i run

```
fcrackzip -D -p pass.txt example.001.zip
```

and got the output

```
PASSWORD FOUND!!!!: pw == 09955gKKFFBxXS
```

i got the password quickly and amazing .. i try to deal with multi zip files on the same time but cannot, in help of fcrackzip they mention how to run the command with multi zip files using 
*2: zip2, USE_MULT_TAB 
but not working
anyhow , now I need script to select the password automatically from dictionary file to print or unzipping the protected zip.

Hope this makes since?

Answer (score 2):

for example:

```
find . -type f -iname \*.zip -print0|xargs -0 -n1 fcrackzip -D -p pass.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

ok thanks everyone i have fix it by create small bash script .. seems is working with me , lol

```
for file in *.zip; do
unz=$(fcrackzip -D -p pass.txt ${file} | awk '{ print $4 }')

unzip -P "${unz}" ${file}" -d `echo "$file" | cut -f 1 -d "."`

done
```